# pgsql rotate table and generate dynamic columns based on values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make a dynamic pivot on pgsql table

**Original table :**

| time | strategy | pnl |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 100 |
| 2 | a | 200 |
| 3 | a | 300 |
| 1 | b | 1000 |
| 2 | b | 2000 |
| 1 | c | 22 |

**target table :**

| time | sum | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1132 | 100 | 1000 | 32 |
| 2 | 2200 | 200 | 2000 | 0 |
| 3 | 22 | 0 | 0 | 22 |

the problem that the **strategy** content is dynamic i can have sometimes over 40 unique values (in this example there are only 3  a,b,c )

i have the following code it looks like a good start but the are some problems i cannot solve

```
SELECT time,
      --sum(case when strategy='a' then pnl else 0 end) AS "a" ,
      --sum(case when strategy='b' then pnl else 0 end) AS "b" ,
      --sum(case when strategy='c' then pnl else 0 end) AS "c"

      --generate the contect above, (when using the code above the function works)
       (SELECT string_agg(clause, ',')
        FROM (SELECT format('sum(case when strategy=''%s'' then pnl else 0 end) AS "%s" ',
                            strategy, strategy) AS clause
              FROM (SELECT DISTINCT strategy FROM server_logs.logs where strategy != '' and subclass = 'pnl') s
              ORDER BY strategy) clauses)
FROM (
select  case when strategy is null then 'system' else strategy end as strategy,
       time,
       sum(case when value::float!=0  then 0::float else value::float end) as pnl
      FROM server_logs.logs
        where subclass='pnl'
        group by rollup(strategy), time
  ) as t
group by time
order by time desc
;
```